# How scrape website if login is required using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape LinkedIn website for some user profiles.

I am using selenium for browser automation.

I need all the profiles under https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/all/?keywords=director%20supply%20chain&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER&page=1

But the site asks for login details.

How should i give my login details in the code?

Comment: They do have api's that you can use. Are you sure the data you need isn't in there?

Comment: There seem to be a lot of search results for exactly this. Don't know how up to date they are but here is a tutorial claiming to do just that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=trSxSmeXCPQ

Answer (score 2):

This code is working

```
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com")
driver.implicitly_wait(6)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="login-email"]""").send_keys(userid)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="login-password"]""").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="login-submit"]""").click()
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/all/? 
keywords=director%20supply%20chain&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER&page=1")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to find the username and password boxes and enter them in. I find this easiest to do with css element ids. Selenium has a `find_element_by_id` method. Check out this little selenium auto login project I made: 
https://github.com/bnorquist/auto_login/blob/master/scripts/login.py#L7

Comment: where should i give my user name and password in the code ?

Comment: Both user name and ps can be inputted in the site.credentials.username and site.credentials.password